# how to get new coordinate for drawing point?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an if clause in function `myMouse()`. in it's condition, if the coordinate of `x` and `y` was in the certain place, I want to draw a point in the **new coordinate** that `myMouse()` **takes from user**!
I'm beginner in openGl. please help me how can I define a drawdot function that draws a point in new coordinates after checking condition. and this is part of my code:

```
void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN && ((x>=30 && x<=70) && ((wh-y)>=400 && (wh-y)<=440)))
        {status=1;
    drawdot(x,y);}
```

Comment: Question title and question text ask for different things. Which one is it?

Comment: I want to draw point in new coordinate. not from the coordinate in condition. I want to get new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store each x and y in 2D array then you can access to the previous points for drawing line or the other polygons.